# How to calculate the probability of a given character in a string using slices of this string?

Tags: string, probability, bioinformatics

Given a string, such as `01001010101001101011`, we can randomly sliced multiple substrings. Assume that during the slicing, due to some unexpected noises, some characters may flip(`0->1` or `1->0`).  For example:

```
Position: 0123456789.........
String:   01001010101001101011

slice1:    1001110101000
slice2:       1010111001111
slice3:       10101
slice4:                1101011
```

`slice1` starts from position 1(assume that the index of a string begins with 0), `slice2` starts from position 4, `slice3` starts from 4, and `slice4` starts from 13. In `slice1`, `0` flips to `1` at position 5 and `1` flips to `0` at position 13.

For one specific position in the original string, if it is `1`, then the probability of flipping to `0` in a slicing is 0.1; and vice versa(i.e.`Prob(0->1)=0.1`).

The problem is: **if we only have multiple slices(the length of each slice may vary) and their starting positions in the string, and we don't know the original string, given an arbitrary position in the original string, how can we calculate the probability that position is a `1`?**

Assume most positions will be covered at least once in slices, and we have following parameters:

```
p01=0.1; // Probability a ‘0’ in string but flipped to a ‘1’ in a slice
p10=0.1; // Probability a ‘1’ in string but flipped to a ‘0’ in a slice
p1=0.5;  // Prior probability that any given position in string is a ‘1’
```

We can also assume that the string is a random string of 0s and 1s, and during slicing, each position is sampled independently.

For the above example string and four slices, we already have following probabilities for each position:

```
Pos Prob
0   0.500
1   0.900
2   0.100
3   0.100
4   0.999
5   0.100
6   0.999
7   0.001
8   0.999
9   0.500
10  0.988
11  0.012
12  0.012
13  0.900
14  0.988
15  0.500
16  0.988
17  0.100
18  0.900
19  0.900
```

I spent hours trying to figure out how to get above answers, and I can count the numbers of `0`s and `1`s in all slices for each position with a program. However, I still cannot find a **formula** or **model** or **algorithm** to calculate the probabilities, especially for positions 4(`1,1,1`), 5(`1,0,0`), 9(`0,1`), 13(`0,1,1`).

Comment: ask http://www.biostars.org/ ?

Comment: @Pierre In my opinion, this question is more about statistical modelling than about biology or programming. Once a suitable model is found the algorithm or formula will be straight forward.

Comment: Yes, I agree with cel. Although this problem is a simplified deep sequencing method, I also think it is a pure probability problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each position in the string, we have **n** amount of bits (information from the slices). Let's say **k** of those are '1'.

In your example, at position 5 we have n=3 and k=1.

To find the probability **p** that the original string contains a '1' in that position, we will be using [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). We first need to find the probability that a '0' in the original string would have produced k=1, if n=3 (so one 1 and two 0s). In this case: **0.243**. Then we need the probability a '1' would have produced k=1 if n=3. This is **0.027**. Now we finally have our probability it was a '1' in the original string: p = 0.027 / (0.243 + 0.027) = **0.1**

I'm assuming you can get n and k (for each position) by yourself. Code in C# or Java:

```
private float p1 = 0.5;
private float p01 = 0.1;
private float p10 = 0.1;

private float probItsOne(int n, int k)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return p1;
    float probByZero = binomial(n, p01, k); // probability a '0' would generate this k, given n
    float probByOne = binomial(n, p10, n - k);
    return probByOne / (probByZero + probByOne);
}

// (this p is not the same as in my explanation)
private float binomial(int n, float p, int k)
{
    return combinations(n, k) * Math.Pow(p, k) * Math.Pow(1 - p, n - k);
}

private int combinations(int n, int k)
{
    return (int)(factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k));
}

private long factorial(int n)
{
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; n++)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You are right! The binomial distribution models the total number of successes in repeated trials...